# concat 2 dimensional cell array with strings to one large string in matlab

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation

I have the folliwing cell are of strings:

```
myCellArray = {'M1','M36','M129'}
```

I would like to display the contents of `myCellArray` in an error message to the user of my function. If I simply do:

```
error(['Please correct elements with IDs:' cell2mat(myCellArray)])
```

The error looks like: **Please correct elements with IDs:M1M36M129**

How can I adjust the code that the elements are separated by a comma, so the error shown would be: **Please correct elements with IDs:M1, M36, M129**.

I tried something like:

```
a=num2cell({ ...
  myCellArray; ...
  repmat( ...
    {', '}, ...
    1, ...
    length(myCellArray) ...
  ) ...
});
b=strcat(a(:));
```

But this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `sprintf`

```
>> error(['please correct elements with IDs: ', sprintf('%s, ', myCellArray{:}) ] )
```

results with

> ??? please correct elements with IDs: M1, M36, M129,

Comment: `error('...%s%s',sprintf('%s, ',myCellArray{1:end-1}), sprintf('%s.', myCellArray{end}))` to avoid last comma.

Comment: @OlegKomarov the last comman is annoying, but is it worth all the trouble for removing it?

Comment: Depends, and that's why I commented instead of answering :).